# Запись данных из requests запроса в БД django по расписанию

Tags: база-данных, django, request

Пытаюсь разобраться с работой планировщика **django-rq-scheduler**.
Имеется небольшая модель:

```
class Currency(models.Model):
name = models.CharField('Название валюты', max_length=20)
price_usd = models.DecimalField(
    'Курс в долларах', max_digits=20, decimal_places=10, blank=True, null=True)
last_updated = models.IntegerField('Последние обновление')


def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s' % (self.name, self.price_usd, self.last_updated)
```

1. Вот код,которым пытаюсь записать данные:

   ```
       import requests
       from .models import Currency
       from django_rq import job


       @job
      def save_exchange_rates():
           url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'
           repositories = requests.get(url).json()
           for exchange in repositories:
               cur = Currency()
               cur.name = exchange['name']
               cur.price_usd = exchange['price_usd']
               cur.last_updated =  exchange['last_updated']
               cur.save()
   ```

   второй вариант:

> ```
> Currency.objects.create(name=exchange['name'],
>                                 price_usd=exchange['price_usd'],
>                                 last_updated=exchange['last_updated'],)
> ```

При попытке выполнить скрипт вручную, возникает ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "task.py", line 2, in 
>           from models import Currency
>         File "/home/pavel/django/market_coins/market_capitalizations/exchange_rates/models.py",
>   line 10, in 
>           class Currency(models.Model):
>         File "/home/pavel/django/market_coins/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 100, in **new**
>           app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
>         File "/home/pavel/django/market_coins/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
>   line 244, in get_containing_app_config
>           self.check_apps_ready()
>         File "/home/pavel/django/market_coins/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
>   line 127, in check_apps_ready
>           raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
>       django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Подскажите в чем может быть причина и правильно ли я пытаюсь данные записать?

2. И еще вопрос про Repeatable Jobs в админке. Можно ли там передать
   параметр к выполняемой функции в поле **Callable:** .Для примера,
   хочу вызывать функцию для каждой валюты с разным расписанием, т.е. для каждой валюты создать отдельное задание:

   ```
   @job
   def save_exchange_rates(coin):
           url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/{}/'.format(coin)
           exchange = requests.get(url).json()
           cur = Currency()
           cur.name = exchange['name']
           cur.price_usd = exchange['price_usd']
           cur.last_updated =  exchange['last_updated']
           cur.save()
   ```

[image: админка с Repeatable Job]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было импорт модулей сделать:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'market_capitalizations.settings'
from django_rq import job
import django
django.setup()
import requests
from exchange_rates.models import Currency
```

И перенести скрипт в корень проекта в папку с manage.py

Планировщик так и не подхватывает скрипт, хотя раз в минуту выполнять поставил.. Есть идеи?

Comment: может проще использовать crontab и просто из него запускать данный файл по расписанию?

Comment: В итоге все на celery настроил.